# Getting "One or more data series provided.." while trying to calculate stats

Tags: python

I'm trying to calculate basic stats with the ffn (Financial Functions for Python) module like:

```py
import ffn
prices = ffn.get('msft,race,msft', start='2020-04-01')
stats = prices.calc_stats()
```

But then get:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/martin/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ffn/core.py", line 1228, in calc_stats
    return GroupStats(*[prices[x] for x in prices.columns])
  File "/home/martin/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ffn/core.py", line 829, in __init__
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: ('One or more data series provided', 'have same name! Please provide unique names')
```

Why is this happening ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the `calc_stats()` method all tickers in the first argument must be
unique, e.g. in 'msft,race,msft', "msft" is listed twice so you get that error.

Something like this works:

```py
import ffn
prices = ffn.get('msft,race,post', start='2020-04-01')
stats = prices.calc_stats()
```